# Setting XML attribute with PHP

Tags: php, xml, attributes

I'm trying to create .xml files with PHP, with a certain layout, using SimpleXMLElement.
Currently I'm struggling setting an attribute to an element.

What I tried so far:

```php
<?php
$att = 'name="tc1"';
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<configuration/>');

$track = $xml->addChild('testcase');
$track->attributes()->$att;
$track->addChild('pfad', "none");
$track->addChild('aktiv', "false");
$track->addChild('file', "none");
$track->addChild('wert', "none");


Header('Content-type: text/xml');
print($xml->asXML());
?>
```

I can't figure out, why it's only displaying:
( XML Output: )

```xml
<configuration>
  <testcase>
    <pfad>none</pfad>
    <aktiv>false</aktiv>
    <file>none</file>
    <wert>none</wert>
 </testcase>
</configuration>
```

...instead of:

```xml
...
<testcase name="tc1">
...
```

Could you please help me set the attribute correctly?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$track->addAttribute('name', 'tc1');
```

[Source](http://www.cs.wcupa.edu/docs/php/simplexmlelement.addattribute.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot! ...how could I miss addAttribute() ...

Comment: Everyone starts somewhere :) Glad I could help